# Let $A$ and $B$ be $n \times n$ complex matrices. Pick out the true statements.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A$ and $B$ be $ n \times n$ complex matrices. Pick out the true statements:
>
> **a)** If $A$ and $B$ are diagonalizable, so is $A + B$
>
> **b)** If $A$ and $B$ are diagonalizable, so is $AB$
>
> **c)** If $A^2$ is diagonalizable, then $A$ is diagonalizable
>
> **d)** If $A$ is real symmetric and $A^2$ is diagonalizable, then $A$ is diagonalizable.

I am not sure about **a** and **b**, but **c** is true and **d** is false, as $A^2$ is diagonalizable so $D=PA^2P^{-1}$ and we can write $\sqrt{D}=\sqrt{P}A\sqrt{P^{-1}}$, as $A$ is real symmetric so it may have negative eigenvalue so square root may not exists, but if it were complex matrix then **d** would have also true. am I right?

Comment: Hint for c: think about nilpotent matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints for first two parts:

a)Try $A=\left(\begin{array}[cc]\\
1&3\\
1&2
\end{array}\right)B=\left(\begin{array}[cc]\\
-1&-2\\
-1&-2
\end{array}\right)$.

[edited] b)

$A=\left(\begin{array}[cc]\\
0&0\\
1&1
\end{array}\right)B=\left(\begin{array}[cc]\\
1&0\\
1&0
\end{array}\right)$.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say on b)

Comment: @i707107 Thanks for spotting that.

Comment: Great! that example is precisely what I had too.

Comment: just to clear my doubt or mental blockage could you confirm me that identity matrix and zero matrix are diagonalizable or not? any diagonal matrix diagonalizable?any diagonal matrix with distinct diagonal entries will be diagonalizable that I agree

Comment: The zero, identity an diagonal matrices are diagonalisable. For the zero matrix $D=0$. $I=III^{-1}$. $D=IDI^{-1}$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

c) Can $A^2=0$?

d) Ignore the assumption that $A^2$ is diagonalizable and think about it.

Comment: @i707107 Now it should be better, the former hint was about real matrices.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. Good to know, thanks.

Comment: I do not understand any one of your hints, it would be better if you make example and answer me. Thank you

Comment: sor ry for c I understand if A is  nilpotent with degree 2 then $A^2=0$

Comment: @miosaki Yes, now the question for c) is whether you know a non-diagonalizable nilpotent matrix? For d) I suggest you look into the literature you have for your course, or into the book this exercise is taken from, whatever applies.